# How may I diagnose Intellisense's problem with my assembly?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, intellisense, roslyn

My C# .NET 6.0 projects use my C++/CLI assembly.  I can build, run, and debug them (down to unmanaged C++) with no problems.

But whenever the *Release* configuration is current, my Error List window goes from zero errors to 1000+.  Virtually all of them appear to be a case of Intellisense not seeing my C++/CLI assembly.  The error messages are like: `The type or namespace name 'Sdk' does not exist in the namespace 'MyCompany' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`.

When I look at the assembly reference in Solution Explorer under each C# project's dependencies, it has that little yellow triangle with an exclamation point:

[image]

But that's all.  There is no tooltip error message, no output window message that I can see, nothing.  Intellisense just rejects my DLL and won't tell me why.

Is there some way I can get Visual Studio to tell me why Intellisense doesn't like the Release version of my assembly when it builds and runs pefectly?

The assembly lives in the same build output folder as all the C# projects that use it and all the unmanaged C++ DLLs that it uses.

Every one of my C# projects references it like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="MyCompany.Sdk_v143">
      <HintPath>$(OutDir)\MyCompany.Sdk_v143.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

I build with Visual Studio 2022 version 17.1 and .NET 6 (even the C++/CLI assembly) I've tried comparing release vs debug build settings of all projects and I do not see any differences that look like they could cause this.

Each C# project has Code Analysis Settings like this:

[image]

Is there an Intellisense log file or diagnostic window somewhere that I can check?

Comment: One thing that might help to try would be to change it from using HintPath to directly do something like `<Reference Include="$(OutDir)\MyCompany.Sdk_v143.dll" />`; that hopefully will at least show in solution explorer where it's trying to be resolved from and you can see if you have OutDir set wrong or something.

Comment: Also OutDir being used that way implies you're doing something like dropping all your binaries into a single folder for all projects? Do you have other specific customizations there?

Comment: My build process is as follows:  Build all unmanaged C++ DLLs and their C++/CLI wrapper into one big output folder.  When all that is done, a build step copies them all to a second output folder for all the managed C# assemblies.  This is essentially two solutions in side-by-side folders married into one big solution.  So when the C# assemblies begin their builds, the appropriate (release or debug) version of the the C++/CLI DLL (and unmanaged C++ DLLs it uses) are already there, waiting in the output folder they already plan to use.

Comment: I will try your suggestion about the Reference Include

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work.  As soon as I did that, not only did Intellisense report errors but I could not even build.  The name of my assembly in the project tree (under "Dependencies" changed to that full path.  However I can report that editing the `HintPath` to remove the backslash after the `$(OutDir)` appears to have fixed the issue.   `$(OutDir)` already has a backslash in it so maybe the 2 backslashes confused Visual Studio?  I have no idea really.  All I know is my release-mode error list matches the Debug one again.